# Slow performance Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04

I I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I kinda regret it now because the system became so much slower, boot takes 10 whole minutes and apps have more than 2 sec delay to start.
has anyone had similar problems with this version ? and how to fix it ?

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 4.507s (firmware) + 13.707s (loader) + 4.101s (kernel) + 4min 55.871s (userspace) = 5min 18.186s graphical.target reached after 4min 55.612s in userspace
```

I ran systemd-analyze blame :

```
4min 20.449s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
3min 14.185s vboxadd.service                                      
 19.294s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
 17.419s dev-sda4.device                                      
 11.793s accounts-daemon.service                              
 11.749s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
 10.988s udisks2.service                                      
  8.715s NetworkManager.service                               
  8.036s polkit.service                                       
  7.847s dev-loop10.device                                    
  7.420s dev-loop8.device                                     
  7.351s dev-loop9.device                                     
  7.132s dev-loop1.device                                     
  7.130s dev-loop0.device                                     
  7.103s dev-loop2.device                                     
  6.910s dev-loop4.device                                     
  6.804s avahi-daemon.service                                 
  6.590s systemd-resolved.service                             
  6.579s snapd.service                                        
  6.475s iio-sensor-proxy.service                             
  6.211s ModemManager.service                                 
  6.189s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
  5.931s switcheroo-control.service
```

lines 1-23

Comment: Turn off Secure Boot in your BIOS and see if that helps. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I restarted the system, secure boot was already disabled, I disabled legacy support on my way, didn't seem to help much, here is the results now  systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 2.956s (firmware) + 11.342s (loader) + 3.748s (kernel) + 2min 6.769s (userspace) = 2min 24.817s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 6.107s in userspace

Comment: What version VirtualBox do you have installed? Show me `dpkg -l *irtual* | grep ii`. Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model of your computer.

Comment: @heynnema VM version is 6.1.6                                                                                      dpkg -l *irtual* | grep ii
dpkg-query: no packages found matching PlayOnLinux's virtual drives
dpkg-query: no packages found matching VirtualBox VMs
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version  shows F.04                                                                                  I have an HP-Pavilion-Sleekbook-14-PC, i3 Intel Core Processor, 4GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2), and 320gb disk capacity

Comment: There's a couple of different model designations for your PC. Can you please check for a more complete/exact model # for me?

Comment: @heynnema this should be the one https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03536202

Comment: That link takes me to a blank page.

Comment: @heynnema here Product Name
14-b000ee
Product Number
C5R85EA
Microprocessor
1.8 GHz Intel Core i3-3217U
Chipset
Intel HM77 Express
Microprocessor Cache
3 MB L3 cache
Memory
4 GB DDR3
Memory Max
Upgradeable to 8 GB DDR3 (2 DIMM)
Video Graphics
Intel HD Graphics 4000
Hard Drive
500 GB SATA (5400 rpm)
Up to 24 GB partition for system recovery

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've put together an answer. If it solves the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema when i follow the link it doesn't pull up any drivers with ubuntu selected as operating system until i change it to windows , is it okey to download the ones of windows?

Comment: Yes, you have to select the Windows OS to be able to see the BIOS update. Download the update. Do you have Windows installed?

Comment: @heynnema no I have windows 7 it on VM

Comment: Windows 7 in a VM won't help you do a BIOS update. If your BIOS doesn't support self-updating, you may have to build a FreeDOS USB flash drive to do the BIOS update.

Comment: I'm very much regretting it as well. The DM is broken (Auto-login breaks GDM3), apps like Firefox take *forever* to start up and I cannot get printing to work reliably on my (several years old now) HP P1102W printer. I'm thinking very seriously now about whether I want to downgrade to 18.04 or install Pop-Os or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

HP Pavilion Sleekbook 14-b000ee

You have BIOS version F.04.

There's a newer BIOS available, version F.1D, dated May 8, 2016. This newer BIOS **may** speed up your boots. It can be downloaded from [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Pavilion-14-Sleekbook/5296230/model/5314612).

Note: Make sure that the web page matches your exact model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: My exact model is the 14-b000ee